# Amazon EC2 Server very basic questions

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, real-time, backend

I am trying to develop my **iOS** application that requires a backend for simple CRUD functionality and also a server that helps me link up players and handle real-time multiplayer game logic.

I am using AWS DynamoDB to store my user's data and believe I would need to set up an EC2 instance to help me with my multiplayer game feature. I am completely new in this area and I hope to get some help in these few elementary questions:

1. Does the different instance (linux or windows) matter?
2. What language is it required to set up the server-side code? Or is server-side coding necessary?
3. If the language in the server-side is different from that of xcode's how does it handle the calls? (Please bear with me if this is really fundamental)
4. Is there any guide for setting up AWS EC2, and must those guide be specific to iOS for my app to work?

Thank you so much for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably
2. Whatever you want to use, and yes it is necessary
3. You have different options here, you can do everything from sockets to REST or SOAP.
4. An EC2 instance is, as far as your concerned, just a server running a back end service for your application. You need to figure how you want the application to work first. It doesn't matter if you decide to host it on ec2 or another service.